# How to set the width of an error message in R?

Tags: r, error-handling

I know you can set the width of your R output

```
> options(width = 20)
> 1:30
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5
 [6]  6  7  8  9 10
[11] 11 12 13 14 15
[16] 16 17 18 19 20
[21] 21 22 23 24 25
[26] 26 27 28 29 30
```

How do you set the error message to be width 20?

```
> options(width = 20)
> IWantMyErrorMessageToBeWidth20
Error: object 'IWantMyErrorMessageToBeWidth20' not found
```

Comment: I'm not sure that there's an easy way to do this. `rlang` manages it, but it seems to do so by catching the errors, re-formatting their messages using string manipulation, then re-throwing them with these formatted messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, you can catch the error and process it like this

```
tryCatch(
  IWantMyErrorMessageToBeWidth20,
  error = function(err) {
    msg <- conditionMessage(err)
    stop(substr(as.character(msg), 1, 20), call. = FALSE)
  }
)

# Error: object 'IWantMyError
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is very interesting for me, and I would like to try to answer it. Please correct me if I'm wrong in some parts.

When you run `1:30`, R will execute `print(1:30)`(Or more specifically, `print.default(1:30)`) behind the screen. Debugging inside this function, you will find that if you don't provide one argument **width**, it will directly use the width set in `options()`. To change the output from `print()`, you can either change the width in `options()` or write the code like `print(1:30, width=10)`. Therefore, you can control the width in the code.

However, `IWantMyErrorMessageToBeWidth20` are handled in another way. I assume R will first check if `IWantMyErrorMessageToBeWidth20` exists in the memory, and find there's no object called `IWantMyErrorMessageToBeWidth20`, and then trigger the internal stop function in the R interpreter. I guess there's no width argument in the internal stop function.

Therefore, I would suggest you to follow Allan's advice.